# Use Apache Superset with Docker

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I want to run Superset with Docker on Windows. I downloaded the application image from DockerHub, then I executed this command `$ docker run -d -p 8080:8088 -e "SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY=your_secret_key_here" --name superset_dockerhub apache/superset`

- I setup the local admin account
  `docker exec -it superset_dockerhub superset fab create-admin --username admin --firstname Superset --lastname Admin --email devia05.simplon.afpar@gmail.com --password admin`
- I did steps 2 to 5 as in the tutorial (I replaced superset with superset_dockerhub)

I can access the home page (on
`http://localhost:8080/superset/welcome/`)
When I click on the `+Dashboard` button, I stay on the home page and I get these errors:

[image]

How to properly run Apache Superset using Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did steps 2 to 5 as in the tutorial

What tutorial? Do you mean the [Superset documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose)?

Instead of doing all additionally required steps like setting up a metadatabase, creating admin user etc by yourself, just run the stack via `docker compose`:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
cd superset
git checkout 3.0.0
TAG=3.0.0 docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up -d
docker compose logs -f
```

Comment: thank for your help, I removed `TAG=3.0.0` because it doesn't know the command

Comment: Keep in mind: running `docker compose up` without the `TAG` variable means your are running `latest` Superset which is not stable.